# How do I apply the multiple orderBy filter with array in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

I have to filter the list of an array using the `orderBy` filter. In my case, having multiple `orderBy` is not working, only with a single `orderBy` is it working properly. How do I implement that?

[image: img1]

```
//here  we create the product array and display the array in the HTML page.
var app=angular.module("App",[]);
app.controller("Cont",function($scope){

        var product = [
                          {:"110",ename:"Harry",esalary:"25000",ecity:"Agar"},
                          {pid:"109",ename:"potter",esalary:"11000",ecity:"US"},
                          {pid:"101",ename:"Peter",esalary:"1200",ecity:"London"},
                          {pid:"104",ename:"Janifer",esalary:"12000",ecity:"Bejing"},
                          {pid:"103",ename:"Selena",esalary:"35000",ecity:"England"},
                          {pid:"102",ename:"Lokesh",esalary:"32500",ecity:"Malwa"},
                          {pid:"108",ename:"Gotm",esalary:"8910",ecity:"Ujain"},
                          {pid:"106",ename:"Soni",esalary:"16000",ecity:"bhopal"},
                         ]     
                        $scope.products=product; 
                   });
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Cont">    
        <form align="center">
        <table align="center" border="2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th>pid</th>
                    <th>ename</th>
                    <th>esalary</th>
                    <th>ecity</th>
                 </tr>   
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in products | orderBy:['pid','ename','esalary']">
                    <td>{{x.pid}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.ename | uppercase}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.esalary }}</td>
                    <td>{{x.ecity}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body
    </html>
```

Comment: did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);
app.controller("Cont", function($scope) {
  var product = [
  {
    'pid': "110",
    'ename': "Harry",
    'esalary': "25000",
    'ecity': "Agar"
  },
  {
    'pid': "109",
    'ename': "potter",
    'esalary': "11000",
    'ecity': "US"
  },
  {
    'pid': "101",
    'ename': "Peter",
    'esalary': "1200",
    'ecity': "London"
  },
  {
    'pid': "104",
    'ename': "Janifer",
    'esalary': "12000",
    'ecity': "Bejing"
  }]
  $scope.products = product;
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.7" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Cont">
  <form align="center">
    <table align="center" border="2">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>pid</th>
          <th>ename</th>
          <th>esalary</th>
          <th>ecity</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in products | orderBy:'pid' | orderBy:'ename'">
          <td>{{x.pid}}</td>
          <td>{{x.ename | uppercase}}</td>
          <td>{{x.esalary }}</td>
          <td>{{x.ecity}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sir,here ecity is filtered,pid is not filtered.

Comment: @Kapil707 No you cannot order by pid, because orderby is applied to the entire row. Alterantively you can use some angular table directive. mark as answer if it has helped

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in products | orderBy:['pid','ename']">
          <td>{{x.pid}}</td>
          <td>{{x.ename | uppercase}}</td>
          <td>{{x.esalary }}</td>
          <td>{{x.ecity}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Why did you remove `esalary` from `orderBy`?

Comment: Its not working.i am agree with the Mistalis sir,why did you remove esalary from orderBy?